# Collapse dictionaries of json into one json

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I see lots of almost similar questions around this one, but really couldn't get this worked out.

I have JSON responses as below, which I want to collapse into 1 JSON object

```
>>> responses
[
{'result': [{'number': 'INC0010001'}]}, 
{'result': [{'number': 'INC0010002'}]}, 
{'result': [{'number': 'INC0010003'}]}, 
{'result': [{'number': 'INC0010004'}]}, 
{'result': [{'number': 'INC0010005'}]}]
```

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "number": "INC0010001"
    },
    {
      "number": "INC0010002"
    },
    {
      "number": "INC0010003"
    },
    {
      "number": "INC0010004"
    },
    {
      "number": "INC0010005"
    }  ]
}
```

I've tried this but it will keep overwriting as it's key-based.

```
result = {}
for d in responses:
    result.update(d)
```

Edit: I rarely play around with JSON format. So it's quite challenging dealing with them.

The final output needs to use double quote as opposed to single quote. For example, `'result'` should be `"result"`, same with `"number"` and `"INC00XXXXX"`.

And also note that,

`[{'number': 'INC0010001'}]` should become `{"number": "INC0010001"}`

Notice how the brackets are not removed, and single quote replaced with double quote.

In some cases, `INC` may have actual double quotes as well such as `INC"fdas"`.
So I guess, it needs to be `{"number": "INC\"fdas\""}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
output = {"result":[]}
for d in responses:
  output["result"] += d["result"]
print(output)
```

Comment: You have the closest answer except for the double quote. I notice that Python doesn't accept double quote in a dictionary, so the result is still in single quote `{'result': [{'number': 'INC0010001'}, {'number': 'INC0010002'}, {'number': 'INC0010003'}, {'number': 'INC0010004'}, {'number': 'INC0010005'}]}`

Comment: The internal representation of Python strings is the same whether you use single quotes or double quotes. My guess is that you want to print out the dictionary and see double quotes around the keys? In that case, you would need to dump the dictionary to a JSON file or string. `import json` and do `print(json.dumps(output))`

Comment: Thanks for the info, yes you're right, after some further thoughts, I'm using json.dumps because it doesn't alter the actual JSON output into Python's own presentation.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, something to the effect of:

```
In [1]: responses = [
   ...: {'result': [{'number': 'INC0010001'}]},
   ...: {'result': [{'number': 'INC0010002'}]},
   ...: {'result': [{'number': 'INC0010003'}]},
   ...: {'result': [{'number': 'INC0010004'}]},
   ...: {'result': [{'number': 'INC0010005'}]}]

In [2]: {"result": [result for d in responses for result in d['result']]}
Out[2]:
{'result': [{'number': 'INC0010001'},
  {'number': 'INC0010002'},
  {'number': 'INC0010003'},
  {'number': 'INC0010004'},
  {'number': 'INC0010005'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

this?

```py
result = dict()
for d in responses:
    if len(result) == 0:
        result.update({'result': d['result']})
    else:
        result['result'] +=  d['result']
```

Comment: Almost but not really because each item still contains the brackets []. {'result': [{'number': 'INC0010001'}, [{'number': 'INC0010002'}], [{'number': 'INC0010003'}], [{'number': 'INC0010004'}], [{'number': 'INC0010005'}]]}. And for some reasons, this 'responses' are changed by this operation

Comment: I edited to make it clearer, really appreciate your help on this one. Plucking my hair with this json format :D